# Meaning of the headline "Hip-Hop Is the Music of Vinyl Librarians"

Tags: meaning, headlinese

I came across this:

"[Hip-Hop Is the Music of Vinyl Librarians](https://www.nytimes.com/2023/09/15/opinion/hip-hop-vinyl.html)"

I'm having trouble parsing this sentence/phrase because there is not enough words for a foreign to make a good assumption of what it means.

the way I can interpret this is,Hip-Hop Is the Music is for Librarians who enjoy vinyyl but I don't have a clue if I'm right

Comment: The vinyl librarians are those young people who stayed indoors playing record (vinyl) collections that belonged to them or their parents. The author claims that hip-hop is not a by-product of the streets.

Comment: @Mari-Lou, fantastic interpretation. Gave me an insight. you're either a genius or someone really immersed in USA culture or maybe a native USA. thank you!

Comment: A foreigner?? We say non-native English speaker. A foreigner is um estrangeiro. So...

Comment: @Lambie, you know Portuguese?

Comment: Yes, I do. :) I speak it and write it fluently. Sou bi-nacional para assim dizer.

Comment: @Lambie, legal! eu sou fluente em portugues também. qual a sua nacionalidade?

Comment: I would interpret it as "preferred music of people who have a vinyl collection". I assume librarian here is usedin the traditional sense meaning someone with a collection of books (or by extension records, cds, etc.) rather than the modern sense of someone working in a lending library.

Comment: @timchessish, that is good too. I thought librarian  was someone who works at a library. so I was thinking these workers were weel known for liking vinyl and and my interpretation was that Hip-Hop was popular among "these workers". pretty crazy right? a single word meaning chenge it all

Answer (score 1):

"Hip hop" is a  culture and style of music, rap, that uses effects like record scratching and "sampling" of short extracts from other songs.

Vinyl is a plastic substance that is used (among other things) for making records.

A Vinyl librarian is not a common expression, but I'd take it to mean "Someone who collects and collates records.

Thus "Hip hop is the music of vinyl librarians".  The people who made (and make) hip-hop are record collectors, and music geeks (rather than street performers).